# Request help understanding Ajax scope when using 'this' in reference to a JS class that the Ajax code is contained in

Tags: javascript, ajax, class, scope, undefined

I have a django web project where the client invokes server-side python code to send data to a third-party service and receive a response using ajax. I have all the client side functionality bundled into a class because there are variables I need the ajax callback function to be able to access. I was hoping a class would help this scoping issue I seem to be having, but the function being called by my ajax code upon success has no idea what context it's in.

My server response contains a list of words I want to render to the screen. I have a wrapper class containing an unordered list object that I've made an instance of in my main class that contains my function that contains my ajax code and another function that the ajax calls upon success. In the success function in the class, I'm using `this` to refer to my list object I have defined in my main class. The function invoking the ajax says my list is defined, but the function being called by the ajax says it's undefined.

```
function MainClass(...){

   /* Variable I'm trying to access from my ajax callback. */
   this.wordlist = new UnorderedList();

   this.onAjaxRequest(data){
      console.log(this.wordlist); /* defined */         

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken,
            data: data   
        },
        success: this.onAjaxSuccess
    });   
   }

   this.onAjaxSuccess(words){
      this.wordlist.updateList(words); /* undefined */
   }
}
```

I have discovered through other posters that doing this: `success: this.onAjaxSuccess(this)` seems to work (it feels like type casting to me). My `this.wordlist` reference in `onAjaxSuccess` is now defined, but the parameter being passed in is no longer my server response, but now a reference of my `MainClass`. I understand it is literally passing the entire object because of `(this)`, but how do I get my server response data doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind `this` function context to `onAjaxSuccess` in the function declaration itself.

```js
function MainClass(){

 /* Variable I'm trying to access from my ajax callback. */
 this.wordlist = ['hi','buddy'];

 this.onAjaxRequest =  function(data){
  console.log(this.wordlist, 'onAjaxRequest'); /* defined */

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
   data: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: null,
    data: data
   },
   success: this.onAjaxSuccess
  });
 }

 this.onAjaxSuccess =  (function(words){
  console.log(this.wordlist, 'onAjaxSuccess'); /* defined */
 }).bind(this);
}

var mainClass = new MainClass();
mainClass.onAjaxRequest();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the function reference to the object, so that `this` will work correctly within it. Use:

```
success: this.ajaxSuccess.bind(this)
```

Or you can use an arrow function:

```
success: words => this.ajaxSuccess(this)
```